# How to convert row data into column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My query is

```
select distinct b.Emp_Name,a.emp_id,a.date,a.status,b.Emp_F_H,b.Emp_Gender,b.Emp_DOJ,c.Dept_Disc
from dbo.Attendance_Details a
inner join dbo.Employee_Master b on a.emp_id=b.emp_id
inner join dbo.Department_Details c
  on b.Dept_Id=c.dept_id 
    and a.Fromdate='2011-09-01 00:00:00.000'
    and a.todate='2011-09-30 00:00:00.000'
order by b.emp_name
```

I want Output like

```
emp_name emp_id  emp_f_h doj      emp_gender  dept 1 2 3 4 5..upto 31 column for status 
kamal    emp_1  b.singh  1/1/2011  male      hr   p A P P P...upto 31
ramesh emp_2  singh  1/1/2011  male          Fc   p A P P P...upto 31....
```

so how i dynamicaly generate 31 colum For single emp id to status column plz help me

Comment: search for PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

Try this article

**Crosstab Pivot-table Workbench**

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/crosstab-pivot-table-workbench/